# Passing a command to custom command prompt from C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a command in a custom .cmd from C#. The problem is that the command is not passed to the prompt when the command prompt is ready. Here is my code:

```
proc1.UseShellExecute = false;
string Command = @"Depanalyzer targets /n Dev\Tools\CleanupPerfCounters.exe";
proc1.FileName = @"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MyCustom.cmd";
proc1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc1.Verb = "runas";
proc1.Arguments ="/k " +  Command;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I see command window opened but the Command not passed to it and there is no output.

Comment: Is this running elevated? If so, you cannot pass any information (e.g. window messages) to a window or process that's elevated higher than the starting process) by design.

Comment: Tried modifying the elevation hierarchy but none of the workarounds work.

Comment: your are only capturing the standard output if your application is throwing an error you should also capture the error output otherwise you won't see anything

Answer (score 0):

Your Command is passed as an argument and that argument looks like it as whitespace. To pass an argument with whitespace you need to wrap that argument in quotes.

```cs
proc1.UseShellExecute = false;
//wrap Command in quotes
string Command = @"""Depanalyzer targets /n Dev\Tools\CleanupPerfCounters.exe""";
proc1.FileName = @"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MyCustom.cmd";
proc1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc1.Verb = "runas";
//add quotes
proc1.Arguments ="/k " +  Command;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Given double quotes but still doesn't work. As mentioned in the above comments i tried to adjust the elevation but none works.